# Parse string in xmllib instead of xmlParseFile

Tags: c++, libxml2

I have string with xml content, writing it into a file and reading it back with xmlParseFile affects performance, if there is a way to parse the string directly, can you please show it with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [`xmlParseMemory`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlParseMemory) instead.

> I have string with xml content

So you should be able to do it like so:

```
const std::string xmlContent = "<something> </something>";
xmlDocPtr doc = xmlParseMemory(xmlContent.c_str(), xmlContent.length());
```